# What's a good way to store large amounts of static data?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I'm currently writing a Windows Store app, and it requires me to include a relative large amount of static data (~1000 different records, each needs a few ints associated). I'm not sure how to approach the problem.

What is a good way to store all this data? It will never be changed in the app as it won't need to be updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you thought of using **Resource Files**?

1. [Make the Best of .NET Resource Files.](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2005/01/01/make-the-best-of-net-resource-files.aspx)
2. [Creating and retrieving    resources in Windows Store apps.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694557.aspx)
3. [Working With .resx files Programatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Althought they are commonly used for Localization strings, you can pretty much use them for any need such as yours (storing large amounts of static text, or even images).

Also, you can compile the resource file into a binary and include it in your production assembly, for performance and maintenance reasons. See last part of link #3 above.

Comment: And they have fast lookup

Comment: Sounds like a really good idea, considering the text part of what I'm storing has translations that I could apply to it. Might be a stupid question, but to verify, it can be read in the C# code and not just via XAML, yes?

EDIT: Nevermind, just looked at the title of one of your links, obviously it can be read in C#. Sorry.

Comment: @Jase Yes. See the section "Retrieving a Specific Resource" in link #3. There's sample C# and VB code too.

Answer (score 2):

- A serializeable file such as XML or JSON.
- A database.
- A generic List written in C#
- An array

Comment: If it will never change, why would you recommend List over Array?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a Collection to store all the data.

e.g.

```
public const List<string> DATA = new List<String>()
{
    "Data1","Data2","Data3","Data4", "Data5", "Data6"
};
```

Comment: I thought of using a collection, but that does involve writing about a thousand lines of that into my code files - it's doable, but seems a bit messy.

Comment: Well...You could store all the data in file and read the contents into the collection.

Comment: What would be a good way to easily read a file into a Dictionary? Is there functions already present or would I have to write new ones to load the data properly?

Comment: You could try something like... File.ReadAllLines("filename").ToList();